# Challah roll and a matzah board for lechem mishnah - any preference?

Tags: shabbat, meal-seudah, challah-shabbat-bread

If one has one challah roll and one matzah board for *lechem mishna* on Shabbat, is there any halacha stating which one should be used to eat from (sliced / broken)?

Offhand, I'm thinking the challah is preferable for these reasons:

- "tadir" - I put this in quotes, as this rule applies when there are two conflicting mitzvoth. But, my point is that challah is eaten more often during the year than matzah which is generally reserved for Pesach. At least, that's with most people.
- If there are many people at the meal, I don't think that one matzah would be enough to give everyone a *kezayit* (IIRC, a *kezayit* is about 3/4 of a matzah board), whereas this would be much easier with challah.

Comment: Maybe also personal preference? Either because it's perhaps an halachic concern (as we find in some places including — very relevant here — what food to say a _b'racha_ on, or because perhaps there is no halachic preference so eat what you prefer.

Comment: Your second point is introducing a confounding variable into the question. If the question is whether it's preferable to eat matzah or challah we must assume that there's enough of both of them for everybody to get the requisite amount. If not, then obviously we should eat from the one which is big enough (or eat from both of them if neither is individually big enough).

Comment: Also to your first point, challah cannot be eaten on Pesach, but matzah can be eaten the entire year. So more of the year is eligible for matzah eating than challah eating.

Comment: @Daniel Re your 1st comment. We would think that one is required to have enough to begin with for everyone at the table. However, I just learned that there is a debate regarding the *lechem Mishnah* requirement whether one fulfills his obligation by the *ba'al habayit* alone having it or everyone needs it. Also, it is common on Pesach that with 3 matzot at a large seder table, one must take more matzot from elsewhere, yet the bracha is made on the kezayit that the *ba'al habayit* has. In short, not everyone agrees that the challah or matzah needs to have kezayit for everyone.

Comment: @DanF In that case, why is "If there are many people at the meal, I don't think that one matzah would be enough to give everyone a kezayit" relevant?